# How do you handle mass updates on multiple projects and services?

Tags: microservices

We have a microservice architecture, meaning we got 10s of repositories. Sometimes some configuration or dependency has to be changed in all of those. Are there any tools or workflows that could help upgrading those without going through all manually?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of solutions exist off-the-shelf.

You can run [Dependabot](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core) or [Renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) on your projects. They detect automatically outdated dependencies and create PR to update them to the currently accepted version. Then if you have a sufficient test coverage (unit tests, functional tests, ...), you can automatically merge those PR. This solution is recommanded by ThoughtWorks in their 2023 radar, as you can see [here](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/automatic-merging-of-dependency-update-prs).

If you want to keep control, you can write a program that loops on all the repository and for each : clone the repo, modify and commit the pom.xml, push the change, and let the pipeline runs and deploys it. Each time you want to update something, you adapt and run the program, with all the burden of testing and then monitoring the progress of that program...